# задача о размене монет (Coin change problem)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, на [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change) решил задачу о размене монет с использованием мемоизации. Однако, мне моё решение, кажется не очень оптимальным. Как его можно улучшить?

Условие. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static long GetWays(int units, int[] coins, Dictionary<string, long> mem)
    {
        if (units < 0 || coins.Length == 0) return 0;
        if (units == 0) return 1;


        var newCoins = new int[coins.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(coins, 1, newCoins, 0, coins.Length - 1);

        var coinsStr = string.Join(",", coins) + units;
        var newCoinsStr = string.Join(",", newCoins) + units;
        var newUnitStr = string.Join(",", coins) + (units - coins[0]);

        long answer = 0;
        if (mem.ContainsKey(newCoinsStr)) answer += mem[newCoinsStr];
        else answer += GetWays(units, newCoins, mem);

        if (mem.ContainsKey(newUnitStr)) answer += mem[newUnitStr];
        else answer += GetWays(units - coins[0], coins, mem);

        if (!mem.ContainsKey(coinsStr)) mem.Add(coinsStr, answer);
        return answer;
    }
```

И еще один вопрос. Я на самом деле не очень понимаю, почему число способов разменять сумму s равно числу способов разменять s с использованием n-1 типом монет + числу способов разменять сумму s - w с использование всех n типов монет.
w - достоинство исключенной. Спасибо.

upd. странно, что ссылка не работает. Вставил скриншот условия, дабыл не перепечатывать.

Comment: опишите чуть подробнее условия задачи, что конкретно должен делать Ваш код.

Comment: А вам не кажется, что было бы неплохо в текст вопроса добавить формулировку задачи? Ваша ссылка ведёт на страницу на английском языке, да ещё и выдаёт прямо сейчас "Something went wrong! Some error occured while loading page for you. Please try again.", а завтра вообще может перестанет жить. И не для всех понятно, что такое "мемо(р?)изация" и как предполагается разменять. Также было бы неплохо указать, что именно вам не нравится в вашем коде. Или это смутное "что-то не нравится, но не знаю что"?

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил условие задачи.Написано правильно (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) 
Мне не нравится словарь с каким-то, как написали ниже, ужасным ключом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кхм, какой вопрос такой и ответ. Решение ужасное. В этой задаче меморизация совсем не нужна, меморизация по строкам - вообще ужас. Вам же прямо в условии написали как решать. Те кто понимают, плюются) Более-менее нормальное решение (на С++ правда).

```
long getWays(long n, vector < long > c){
    long DP[255];
    memset(DP,0,sizeof(DP)); //в C# и так будет 0, С++ надо
    DP[0] = 1;
    for (int i=0;i < c.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - c[i];j++)
            DP[j+c[i]] += DP[j];
    return DP[n];
}
```

Почему работает это, думаю понятно. Теперь если мы хотим использовать меморизацию, это делается примерно так:

```
vector < long > c;
map< pair<int,int>,long> mem;
long getWays(long n, int p){
    if (p >= c.size() || n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (mem.count(make_pair(n,p)))
        return mem[make_pair(n,p)];
    return mem[make_pair(n,p)] = getWays(n-c[p],p) + getWays(n,p+1);
}
///
getWays(n, 0);
```

Учитывая ограничения задачи вместо пары `<n,p>` можно (да и стоит на самом деле) хранить 1 число `<n * 300 + p>`.

Но большого смысла в рекурсии я не вижу, ну не считая что она проще придумается. А ресурсов больше требует.

Comment: Кхм, на такой вопрос лучше даже и не пытаться тогда отвечать.

Comment: @AK да пусть будет, вопрос то я понял. Вопрос по сути - инспекция кода.

Comment: _//как там в C# зануление?_ - никак, оно там не нужно. В принципе, если заменить vector На List<T> или массив и `size()` на `.Count` или `.Length` - получится код на c#

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. Подправил комментарий. Писать на C# не стал, чтобы не думать надо new делать или не надо и подобное)

Comment: @Grundy а как бы вы решали эту задачу. Решение через рекурсию более очевидно для вас или нет?

Comment: @pavel, я пока вообще не пойму, что за магия в коде (в обоих вариантах) происходит :)

Comment: @Grundy стоит 2 вариант заменить с пары на одно число? Чтобы не так напрягали создания пар?

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Как я понимаю,  в версии с рекурсией, где используется мемоизация вы не проверяете n-c[p],p и n,p+1 на наличие в mem. Соответственно, делаются лишние операции. Или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @AndreyKhristoforov разницы нет, проверить до вызова функции или после. Я предпочитаю в начале функции делать эту проверку. По числу операций можете проверить - разницы нету.

Comment: @pavel Вы не могли бы объяснить какой подход нужно применять к подобного рода задачам. Я имею ввиду как думать над ними. 
Я итеративный подход сейчас вообще не очень понимаю, посижу подумаю и пойму. Однако, принцип решения от этого не становится понятнее.

Comment: @AndreyKhristoforov общее правило. Любая рекурсия с меморизацией сохраняется в ДП. Любое правильное ДП быстрее из-за того что нету проблем со стеком. Как распутывать - больше опыт. Обычно достаточно циклов. Иногда распутать не получается (при циклических зависимостях) тогда очередь иногда используют). В целом - только опыт.

Comment: @pavel только что реализовал вашу рекурсию и она делает больше шагов, чем моя. Получается  следует делать проверку обоих членов выражения на наличие в словаре.